# Null after onClick action

Tags: asp.net

I'm starting with asp.net, but i'm not quite sure what am I doing wrong. Actually my first step in asp is to make a calculator but after 2h of looking for answer i've decided to ask you about that.

I have 10 buttons with [0,1,2...9], 4 action buttons [+,-,*,/] and one button to calculate [=]:

```
int firstNumber, secondNumber;
        Button lastClicked;
        bool isFirstNumberSet;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstNumber = 0;
            isFirstNumberSet = false;
            lastClicked = new Button();

        }

        public void addToTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button number = (Button)sender;
            TextBox1.Text += number.Text;
        }

        public void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isFirstNumberSet.Equals(false)) firstNumber = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            else secondNumber = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            lastClicked = new Button();
            lastClicked = (Button)sender;
            isFirstNumberSet = true;
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }

        public void calculate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (lastClicked.ID)
            {
                case "ButtonPlus":
                    TextBox1.Text = (firstNumber + secondNumber).ToString();
                    isFirstNumberSet = false;
                    break;

                case "ButtonMinus":
                    TextBox1.Text = (firstNumber - secondNumber).ToString();
                    isFirstNumberSet = false;
                    break;

                case "ButtonDziel":
                    TextBox1.Text = (firstNumber / secondNumber).ToString();
                    isFirstNumberSet = false;
                    break;

                case "ButtonMnoz":
                    TextBox1.Text = (firstNumber * secondNumber).ToString();
                    isFirstNumberSet = false;
                    break;
}
```

but when i do for example action like 2 + 2, and after that i hit "=". I get an exception about that code:

switch (lastClicked.ID)

It says that lastClicked is null, but how? after hit "+" this should save sender object to this variable. Am i wrong?

Comment: You can go step by step with the debuger to check if the doSomething function is actually called and lastClicked is set as expected.

Comment: Every time your page is reloaded, your Page_Load() event declares a new lastClicked variable. Because the new button isn't added to the outgoing document, it never receives an ID, hence it is null when your calculate() method is called.

Comment: I checked that and after doSomething sender is correctly passed to lastClicked, but when i do another action like hit any number button, then lastClicked comes to null again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button variable assignment does not persist between postbacks the way you are expecting. When `calculate` fires upon your "=" keyhit, `lastClicked` is now unassigned on this new "round trip," and thus null. When you press one button once, then a second button the next time, there's no memory of the *previous* hit unless you store the value in a field that's captured in the data sent back to the server.

One approach you could explore involves storing the operation that's been selected into a hidden HTML field on your form, and then interrogate that upon hitting the calculate routine. That eliminates the need to try persisting the "lastClicked" button as you have.

Somewhere in your aspx, within your form, you could add:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="Operation" runat="server" />
```

Then, in your codebehind in response to one of your operator buttons:

```
Operation.Value = "Plus";  // or "+" or whatever is appropriate
```

That would then get sent back down to the client on the next trip, and then be part of the data sent back to the server when your `calculate` method is called in response to the "=" button click:

```
 public void calculate(object sender, EventArgs e){

      switch(Operation.Value){
           case "Plus";
              // do the "PLUS" thing
              // and so on

      ... (snip)...
}
```